# Find $f(x)$ such that: $ f'(x) + f(x^2) = 2x + 1 $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the function $f(x)$ that is derivable on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies the equation:

$$ f'(x) + f(x^2) = 2x + 1 \text{ } \text{ } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

> *My attempt:*
>
> Substitute $-x$ for $x$ in the equation, we have a system of 2 equations :
>   \begin{cases} 
> f'(x) + f(x^2) &= 2x + 1\\ 
> f'(-x) + f(x^2) &= -2x + 1
> \end{cases} 
>   Take the difference of them, we have: 
>   $$ f'(x) - f'(-x) =4x $$ 
>   Integrate both sides: 
>   $$ f(x) + f(x) = 2x^2 + C_1 $$
>   Therefore, we have:
>   $$ f(x) = x^2 + C_2 $$

However, this method results in an invalid solution to the original equation. I wonder whether there is another way to solve this problem or why my solution is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want one such function or all of them?

Comment: I think there is only one function that satisfies the equation. Do you find more than one?

Comment: How do you justify $-\int f'(-x)dx=f(x)$?

Comment: $f$ can not be polynomial. If $f$ is polynomial of degree $n$ then we have $(n-1)+2n=1$ which obviously does not work.

Comment: Shouldn’t you have $f(x)+f(-x)$?

Comment: @higgs set u = -x, then du = -dx or dx = -du, so $\int{f'(-x)dx} = -\int{f'(u)du}$

Comment: Yes, but this is not definite integral. It is not $\int f'(x)dx$

Comment: @Aqua yes, I also notice that, but my attempt above gives me this solution, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you're confusing $f'(-x)$ with the derivative of $x \mapsto f(-x)$.  For instance, if $f(x) = e^x$, then $f'(x) = e^x$, $-f'(-x) = -e^{-x}$, and the antiderivative of that is $x\mapsto e^{-x}$, not the original $f(x)$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Oh, so the statement " $\int{f(u)du} = \int{f(x)dx}$ " is not always true?

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=1/x$ solves $f'(x)+f^2(x)=0$, hence if you find a particular solution, you can add $c/x$ to it.

Comment: @KM02 It is, but you can't substitute $u=-x$ in part of an expression, then change $u$ to $x$.  Clayton's got the right antiderivative.

Comment: Did you try using power series?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks for your explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Math1000 Can you elaborate your idea of using power series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write a power series for $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

Then we get that $$f'(x) + f(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n} = 2x+1$$

Breaking this into odd and even powers of $x$, this can be rewritten as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((2n+1)a_{2n+1} + a_n)x^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+2)a_{2n+2}x^{2n+1} = 2x+1$$

From the second sum, we can get that $(2n+2)a_{2n+2} = 0 \to a_{2n+2} = 0$ for $n \ge 1$ and $a_2 = 1$. Then from the first sum, we have these relations.

$$a_1 + a_0 = 1$$
$$3a_3 + a_1 = 0$$
$$5a_5 + a_2 = 0$$
$$7a_7 + a_3 = 0$$
$$9a_9 + a_4 = 0$$
$$...$$

Because $a_4, a_6, a_8, a_{10}, ...$ are $0$, it is also true that $a_9, a_{13}, a_{17}, a_{21}, ..$ are also $0$. Because those are $0$, it is also true that $a_{19}, a_{27}, a_{35}, ...$ are also $0$. By induction, the only ones that are not $0$ are the powers of $x$ where the exponent is either of the form $2^n-1, n \ge 0$ or $3 \cdot 2^n - 1, n \ge 0$.

From $a_2 = 1$, we can get that $a_5 = -1/5$, which leads to $a_{11} = 1/55$. In general, $$a_{3 \cdot 2^n - 1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (3 \cdot 2^k - 1)}$$

Similarly, given $a_1$, we can get that $a_0 = 1-a_1$, and $$a_{2^n-1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2^k - 1)} a_1 $$

From this, we have that $$f(x) = (1-a_1) + x^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (3 \cdot 2^k - 1)} x^{{3 \cdot 2^n - 1}} + a_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2^k - 1)} x^{2^n-1}$$

$a_1$ can be anything. Note that the required functional equation only holds true for $-1 < x < 1$ for my $f(x)$, as it only converges for $-1 < x < 1$.

Comment: The products can be writen as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol (not that this helps much)

Answer (score 3):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which calculates the series approximation for this ODE. It is convergent for $|x| < 1$

```
n = 50;
f[x_, n_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, n}]
A = Table[Subscript[a, k], {k, 0, n}];
dif = D[f[x, n], x] + f[x^2, n] - 2 x - 1;
equs = Take[CoefficientList[dif, x], {1, n + 1}];
B = equs /. Thread[A -> 0];
M = Grad[equs, A];
solA = LinearSolve[M, -B];

f[x_] := f[x, n] /. Thread[A -> solA]

f'[x] + f[x^2] - 2 x - 1

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

[image]